# Run exec on docker running container using python

Tags: python, bash, docker

I'm on centOS 7 trying to run the following on a running docker (v19) container. I'm using python3.6.4, using subprocess.Popen:

```
command = f'docker exec -it 112233443322 bash -c "source /path/to/venv/activate && python3 -m commands.here..."
Popen(command.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: b'path/to/venv/activate: -c: line0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"\'\r\n/path/to/venv/activate: -c: line 1: syntx error: unexpected end of file\r\n'
```

In fact, if I shorten it to just the activate command, I get same error:

```
f'docker exec -it 112233443322 bash -c "source /path/to/venv/activate"
```

I've looked at multiple bash syntax questions but I'm stumped. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't blindly use `str.split()` when your command has quotes in it (because it doesn't know about that shell-specific syntax). Either use [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) or preferably don't mess strings at all but just specify the command as a list to begin with:

```
command = [
    "docker",
    "exec",
    "-it",
    "112233443322",
    "bash",
    "-c",
    # Note how this doesn't have extra quotes anymore
    "source /path/to/venv/activate && python3 -m commands.here...",
]
Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Comment: shlex.split() was it.